# Displaying only posts with 2017 and 2018 in the URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get a report of the pageviews of all posts from my website from 2018 and 2017. The problem is, I can't seem to get both of them in the filter.

The slugs always come out as `/2017/` or `/2018/`. I can insert into an advanced filter to include every page that contains that but it always comes out blank because it is looking for `2017` AND `2018` in the search. How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex filter like this

```
2017|2018
```

Comment: This answer looks like a good start, but it could use a lot more detail.  Where does this regular expression go?   How do you create a regex filter in Google Analytics.  What field should the filter be created against?